# How to not allow browser to store previous values in flask-form StringField?

Tags: flask

After submitting my flaskapp form to make a new response, there is appears a 'quick-suggested' form contains previous input values. How can I restrict appearing this? In fact, I don't understand where it comes from and where it's stores so can't make a relevant ask to google. Dont be sarcastic - it was surprisingly for me, that it's disappear when I try to make this image with scissors!

[it's all about that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIwWw.png)

P.S. all happens in google chrome

Answer (score 1):

Your "google term" would be `form autocomplete`. This is a feature of your browser not flask or any web framework.

You can ask the browser to not autocomplete a form.

```
<form ... autocomplete="off">
```

or an individual field

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

Keep in mind that the browser doesn't have to respect your wishes. Specifically in the case of login fields where browsers will autofill usernames and passwords regardless of `autocomplete="off"`.